# modal(like in vim) windows management for xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, vim

Is there a script, a software or something, with what I will be able to manage the windows and dialogs..for Windows XP?

Comment: since vim is about "modifying text" and handling windows is about .. well .. handling windows, you should explain your idea of "vim for windows" a little bit more.

Comment: Do you mean modes like "hit B to move between buttons, W to move between windows, T to move between text fields, and I to edit text in the fields"?

Comment: @CajunLuke something like that..

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you refer to something like **[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml)**.
<sup>don't see your "modal management" context quite well, hence the doubt.</sup>

Comment: something with modal control like in vim....

Comment: to move windows to find icon etc...

Comment: one mode to move windows, other modes for other stuff..like text edit..or...

Comment: something that will manage with windows on global level...

Comment: @askr: You don't need four comments. Just use one next time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of the various blind-accessibility programs (like JAWS). The only interaction method I've heard of that was like that is Apple's VoiceOver accessibility setup for OS X.

The downside is they tend to be expensive (except VoiceOver, which is free, but is OS X-only).